# Navigate from app to notification settings for the app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a small WP8.1 app. I figured out that it is not possible to change the notification sound in the application itself (or am I wrong here?). Instead I would like to give a link to the sound and notification settings. Is it possible to navigate from my app to the WP8.1 Application settings of my app?

I think i saw that allready in some apps but can't remeber exactly where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with Url Scheme ?
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:personalization"));

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/mt228342.aspx

Comment: Seems not to work on WP8.1 - but thanks anyway... it's a good starting point to search for solutions which work on windows phones

Comment: LaunchUriAsync works on WP8.1 but it seems that there is no way to go directly to the notification settings. You'll have to use WP10 to use ms-settings:sounds :(

Comment: await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-notifications:")); works but it only brings you to the settings of all apps, no way to navigate to the current app.